# JMS JNDI unique name to be accessible from both cluster and standalone instances

Tags: jms, weblogic

I have a weblogic domain with 5 managed servers. 3 of them are in the cluster, and 2 are standalone. One application is deployed on a cluster, second and third on two remaining nodes.
From all 3 applications, I need to access the JMS queues and connection factory with the **same JNDI name** (i.e use jms/q1 from cluster and standalone instances to access the queue). It doesn't have to be the same queue, but the name should be unique in the domain.
I tried to use the distributed queues(UDD), but it doesn't allow mixing the cluster with the non-clustered nodes.

What are the options to achieve this, and keep the JMS queues deployed on the same domain?

Comment: This cannot be done. Each server has information about every queue configured in the domain in its JNDI tree. Why would you ever possibly want to have three different queues under same JNDI? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being ambiguous, i will try to clarify it now. Ideally all the JNDI names **should** point to the same queue (I left the option if that is not possible).

Now about the problem. I have a packaged application (IBM Maximo) that is deployed  on cluster c1, and standalone nodes n1, n2 with 3 different ear files with slight configuration differences(login methods are different for each file). I need to enable the JMS integration to external ESB system. I can't configure the JMS name for each deployment instance, the JNDI is read from the database.

The problem with weblogic is that the **distiributed** queue (UDD) can't be deployed both on cluster **and** standalone instances. Distributed queue has the unique JNDI name across all the nodes deployed on.

One really ugly solution for this could be to use the foreign JNDI server, and point to the external JMS server like HORNETQ. I already tried that and the solution is simple and working, however this is one more system to manage in production, and I want to avoid it.

I know that it can be done, because the distributed queue mechanism is working in weblogic for a cluster, each node points to the same JMS queue with the same JNDI name, but I can't add the standalone nodes. Also, creating separate domains for each standalone instance is not a really desirable option.

Comment: To answer my own question: It is possible to create the queues with the same JNDI name as the distributed ones one for the standalone servers. The only problem is that I will have more than one queue to listen to on the EBS side